# Testing input.focus() in Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme, onfocus

How do I test `input.focus()` in enzyme. I am writing the script with react. My code is below:

```
public inputBox: any;

componentDidUpdate = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.inputBox.focus();
    }, 200);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type = 'number'
                ref = {element => this.inputBox = element } />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Other approach is to test if element gains focus, i.e. `focus()` is called on node element. To achieve this, focused element need to be referenced via `ref` tag like it takes place in your example – reference was assigned to `this.inputBox`. Consider example below:

```
const wrapper = mount(<FocusingInput />);
const element = wrapper.instance().inputBox; // This is your input ref

spyOn(element, 'focus');

wrapper.simulate('mouseEnter', eventStub());

setTimeout(() => expect(element.focus).toHaveBeenCalled(), 250);
```

This example uses Jasmine's [spyOn](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies), though you can use any spy you like.

Comment: Where is `eventStub()` coming from?

Comment: `eventStub` is anything that makes your test pass. In this example you can assume that component `FocusingInput` is listening to 'mouseEnter' event and when this event is triggered (`wrapper.simulate('mouseEnter', ...)` does that) event handler can perform some operations on event like `preventDefault`. To make this work, you need to prepare event stub that will handle this operation and send this stub as second argument of `simulate`. Here is example of my [event stub](https://gist.github.com/mckomo/128bdb43434749ca1a2299d456ed7d7c).

Comment: Wrapping your `expect` in a `setTimeout` is dangerous because your test runner (in my case Jest) might say the test has passed, regardless of what happened inside `setTimeout`. Try it out by putting a `.not` in front of `.toHaveBeenCalled`.

Answer (score 24):

You can use `mount` instead of shallow.
Then you can compare `document.activeElement` and the input DOM node for equality.

```
const output = mount(<MyFocusingComponent/>);

assert(output.find('input').node === document.activeElement);
```

See https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/316 for more details.

Comment: Worked for me. Just to be clear, one needs global `window` and `document` objects for mount to work. I used following code before my first `describe` for that purpose `import jsdom from 'jsdom';
const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.document = doc;
global.window = doc.defaultView;`

Comment: For Jest, make sure you set `--env=jsdom` at CLI, or `"testEnvironment": "jsdom"` in jest config, then you don't need to import it

Comment: This is a great answer because it's the only thing I've found that also works with `useRef` where I haven't found a way to get ahold of the ref inside a function component.

Answer (score 12):

Per **React 16.3** updates... using [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) for anyone visiting this post today, if you rearrange the original component to use the new ref api

```
class InputBox extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.inputRef.current.focus();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <input
                ref={this.inputRef}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Then in your test spec

```
it("Gives immediate focus on to name field on load", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<InputBox />);
    const { inputRef } = wrapper.instance();

    jest.spyOn(inputRef.current, "focus");

    wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
    expect(inputRef.current.focus).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Notice the use of the `inputRef.current` attribute which references the currently assigned DOM node.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue and solved using the following approach:

My setup is Jest (react-create-app) + Enzyme:

```
    it('should set the focus after render', () => {
      // If you don't create this element you can not access the 
      // document.activeElement or simply returns <body/>
      document.body.innerHTML = '<div></div>'

      // You have to tell Enzyme to attach the component to this
      // newly created element
      wrapper = mount(<MyTextFieldComponent />, {
        attachTo: document.getElementsByName('div')[0]
      })

      // In my case was easy to compare using id 
      // than using the whole element
      expect(wrapper.find('input').props().id).toEqual(
        document.activeElement.id
      )
    })
```

Comment: Followed your example but I seem to get a string back from `document.activeElement` rather than an Element object so the test results in "Object is possibly 'null'". Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Thank you for this piece of information. `getElementsByName` should be `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when using `mount` and `useRef` hook:

```
expect(wrapper.find('input').get(0).ref.current).toEqual(document.activeElement)
```

Answer (score 2):

Focus on the particular element can be checked using selectors.

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);

const input = wrapper.find('input');
expect(input.is(':focus')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported. [Enzyme selectors](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html)

Comment: Clean idea! Works for me with Enzyme@3.11.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting by `data-test` attribute or something similar was the most straight forward solution I could come up with.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.inputRef) {
      this.inputRef.focus()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input data-test="my-data-test" ref={input => { this.inputRef = input } } />
    )
  }
}

it('should set focus on mount', () => {
  mount(<MyComponent />)
  expect(document.activeElement.dataset.test).toBe('my-data-test')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);

const input = wrapper.find('input');

expect(input).toHaveFocus();
```