# Test if an element was focused at least once using Jest and Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm trying to test a React component that should focus all the fields having certain ids at least once, using Jest and Testing Library. For example, if the rendered components are:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

const { container } = render(
    <div >
        <input id='input1' />
        <input id='input2' />
        <FocusCertainFieldsAtLeastOnce />
    <div />
);
```

I need to test if `<FocusCertainFieldsAtLeastOnce />` is being able to focus both `<input />` elements with ids 'input1' and 'input2' at least once.

I'm aware how to achieve this using Jest and Enzyme and want something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698676/9580675) but using Jest and Testing Library instead.

Comment: Im not sure about if this example could help you.   

https://codesandbox.io/embed/qz16r4zwyq?codemirror=1

Comment: Hi @Nacho, in this example document.activeElement only checks for the currently focused element. But in my case, the input element might not be the currently focused element. So the check needs to be, "if the input element ever got focused before".